# How can I get installed sql server instances?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I get installed sql server instances from registry? How I can determine default instance??

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are located at 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances

The default instance is always named as MSSQLSERVER.

Answer (score 0):

Instance list:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
```